# How do I use a regex with a Nokogiri::XML::Text object?

Tags: ruby, xml, regex, nokogiri

I have an array called people of these objects:

```
Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fe41985e69c "CEO, Company_1"
Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fe4194dab74 "COO, Company_2 "
Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fe4195eb414 "CFO, Company_3"
```

I want to split the objects at the "," so I tried to do something like this:

```
companies = people.each do | company | 
  company.inner_text.match("/, (.*)/")
end
```

and:

```
occupations = people.each do | occupation | 
  occupation.inner_text.match("/(.*),/") 
end
```

`match` doesn't seem to extract the values I want from the object. I checked rubular.com, and it should work, but I'm getting the same string I put in:  `"CEO, Company_1"` when it should be separated so that `occupations = [CEO, COO, CFO]` and `companies = [Company_1, Company_2, Company_3]`.

How do I split these objects?

Comment: What is returned by `company.inner_text` for each company and what is returned by `occupation.inner_text` for each occupation?

Comment: I meant a sample of returned text. Is it `CEO,XYZ`?

Comment: Please provide your XML. There's no need for you to loop over the same nodes twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you `split` the text?

```
require 'nokogiri'

xml = '<x>
<people>CEO, Company_1</people>
<people>COO, Company_2</people>
<people>CFO, Company_3</people>
</x>
'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(xml)
people = doc.search('people')
companies = people.map do |company| 
  company.text.split(',')
end

pp companies

=> [["CEO", " Company_1"], ["COO", " Company_2"], ["CFO", " Company_3"]]
```

If you want to get rid of the leading spaces before the companies, use:

```
companies = people.map do |company| 
  company.text.split(/,\s*/)
end
=> [["CEO", "Company_1"], ["COO", "Company_2"], ["CFO", "Company_3"]]
```

Or:

```
companies = people.map do |company| 
  company.text.split(',').map(&:lstrip)
end
=> [["CEO", "Company_1"], ["COO", "Company_2"], ["CFO", "Company_3"]]
```

Or use `map{ |s| s.sub(/^\s+/, '') }` instead of the `lstrip`.

See "[How to avoid joining all text from Nodes when scraping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43594656/how-to-avoid-joining-all-text-from-nodes-when-scraping)" also.

Comment: In case the company name contains commas then `split(/,\s*/, 2)` might be useful too.